# Add informations to "reopen" - request

Tags: feature-request, questions

So I want to add some informations to a question which take care of the "[Should I use an antivirus on osx](https://superuser.com/questions/14450/is-anti-virus-software-needed-for-a-mac-os-x-if-so-free-solution)" - question.

So I have clicked the reopen-link. But I'm not able to add any information why I want to reopen it.

Shouldn't a user be able to specify, why he wants that a question reopens?

Btw: I want to add informations to the danger of email-viruses and to spread it to windows-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customary, de-facto official way to handle this is to post a detailed post right here to convince people of its merits and demerits. By posting a more complete question, that lays out your argument for opening the question, you have a better chance of getting those 5 re-open votes.

In this case, I believe its one of those questions that fell victim to changing views on what's on topic here - Its a question soliciting an opinion, rather than solving an actual problem. As you'd notice, its an old question closed 3 years later.

I think, personally this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/14503/10165) sums up the reason it was closed beautifully when it says "When it comes to Mac antivirus, you tread a fine line between getting useful answers, and getting answers that inspire mouth-foaming zealotry"

Comment: So should i leave it, as it was, or should i open a new question. Because i really want to show the people the risks of spreading viruses to windows-users as a osx-user.

Comment: Well, I think the "showing" people part is tricky on Q&A. If you're really willing to put in the effort, why not write something for the blog on the subject?

Comment: Great idea. I didn't know, that normal users are able to write blog-posts. I will do that. Thx for that idea.

Comment: pop by chat - there's a room for blog editors, and talk to kronos.

Comment: I've done it. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you feel a question should be re-opened without changing it, I would suggest making a comment with your reasoning. Do not edit the question to specifically say something such as

> **EDIT**: This should be reopened because blah blah

Make it a comment! Reason being is

1. Edits bump questions; comments do not
2. It does not add value to the question if that's the only edit
3. If it gets reopened, it makes no sense and you'd edit the question to remove the explanation. A comment can be deleted anytime

If you can edit the question to make it better, then that is the preferred way, which also automatically puts it back into the Review queue for high-rep users to vote on.